# Is there a MV** JavaScript framework that is endorsed by/designed for Play (2.1.x and above) Framework (if any)?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm new to Play framework, and I was wondering if it has any "companion" MV** JavaScript framework.

Is there any framework (Backbone.js, Angular.js, Knockout.js, Ember.js etc) that has

- Some sort of official endorsement from TypeSafe
- Play framework community endorsement
- Play integration documentation / tutorials
- Good open source Play framework plugins

If not, is there any MV** framework that one should avoid using for any particular reason with Play?

Comment: To the downvoter, I've spent 1 hour reading FAQ at both SO and programmers.stackexchange, none of them is a perfect match for this question, please be nice, i'ts a valid question and I am sure someone will have a good answer. So if you donwvote because it's not according to the FAQ, please explain why and how it can be improved (or where I should ask it).

Comment: Why I think this question fits the FAQ: 1) it's answerable (yes there is such framework, here it is / no there isn't) 2) it's not subjective because it has clear criteria, it can be logically satisfied with very little opinion involved 3) it's about tools and frameworks and SO is allowing questions about tools and fraemworks. 

If you disagree, please comment and I'll move it to the most relevant SE site / clean it up to match the guidelines / or even delete it if I'm convinced it's not fixable. 

Thanks for the help

Comment: There have been many times I find a question I am eager to ask on stackoverflow but see a "closed as not construtive by XXX". I really hate it. Personally I think you were asking a good question. At least I want to know the answer to it. Just want to say something to show my support to you. Stackoverflow really needs to do something to change this stupid "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format." thing. I feel it hurts SO rather than benefits it.